# Apache Artemis broker not sending messages to SwiftMQ AMQP client

Tags: java, amqp

I am running an Apache Artemis broker, version 1.1.0.

I create a session using the SwiftMQ client like this.

```
AMQPContext ctx = new AMQPContext(AMQPContext.CLIENT);
Connection connection = new Connection(ctx, getBrokerHost(), getBrokerPort(), getUserName(), getPassword());
connection.setExceptionListener((exc) -> log().error(exc, "Problem with AMQP connection to {}", getBrokerHost()));
connection.connect();

// Parameters are maximum number of unsettled input and output messages
session = connection.createSession(50, 50);
```

In one process, I create a producer by

```
session.createProducer(queueName, QoS.AT_LEAST_ONCE)
```

In a separate process, I create a consumer by

```
session.createProducer(queueName, QoS.AT_LEAST_ONCE)
```

With the producer, I can send messages by

```
AMQPMessage result = new AMQPMessage();
result.setAmqpValue(new AmqpValue(new AMQPString(value)));
producer.send(result);
```

This works.  Using JMX, I can see that there are messages in the queue.  When I try to read them by

```
AMQPMessage message = consumer.receive();
```

or

```
AMQPMessage message = consumer.receiveNoWait(listener);
```

where `listener` will send a message to the reading thread to call one of the `receive`s, the call either blocks or returns no message, depending on the version.

JMX shows that the broker thinks there is a consumer for the queue, and that the queue has messages.  The messages are not listed as in delivery, and the queue is not paused.  There is no filter on the queue.

If it matters, the consumer and the producer are running on the same host.  The broker is running in a Docker container (think VM if you do not know Docker) on the same host as the producer and consumer, but it has a different IP address.

I added `consumer.setLinkCredit(100)`, but that did not affect anything.

There could be some Artemis/SwiftMQ incompatibility, but that seems unlikely, as I am able to send messages to the broker.

The broker is pretty much a standard broker.  It was created with

```
/opt/apache-artemis-1.1.0/bin/artemis create artemis  \
                                      --home /opt/apache-artemis \
                                      --user xxx \
                                      --password yyy \
                                      --cluster-user www \
                                      --cluster-password zzz \
                                      --allow-anonymous
```

A second user, with role `amq`, was added.  Two durable queues were predefined.  One of those is the queue being used here.

Is there a reason the messages might not be delivered?  Is there anything else I could usefully check to understand why this is not working?

**Edit**

I have tried with several different queue names.

- frobGetter
- frobRequest
- jms.queue.ExpiryQueue
- jms.queue.DLQ
- jms.queue.PlanningQueue

None of those names work.

Comment: What do you have as queueName?

Answer (score 1):

I've never used the SwiftMQ client before but I was able to get it working with Artemis v1.1.0 and ActiveMQ v5.12.1 using the code shown below.  The trick seems to be that you need to specify the link credit in the createConsumer call, the `consumer.setLinkCredit(100)` seems to have no affect on the consumer as no credit is ever issued to the broker when making this call.

```
package org.apache.activemq.demo;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import com.swiftmq.amqp.AMQPContext;
import com.swiftmq.amqp.v100.client.Connection;
import com.swiftmq.amqp.v100.client.Consumer;
import com.swiftmq.amqp.v100.client.ExceptionListener;
import com.swiftmq.amqp.v100.client.Producer;
import com.swiftmq.amqp.v100.client.QoS;
import com.swiftmq.amqp.v100.client.Session;
import com.swiftmq.amqp.v100.generated.messaging.message_format.AmqpValue;
import com.swiftmq.amqp.v100.messaging.AMQPMessage;
import com.swiftmq.amqp.v100.types.AMQPString;
import com.swiftmq.amqp.v100.types.AMQPType;

public class SwitftMQTest {

    public void run() throws Exception {
        AMQPContext ctx = new AMQPContext(AMQPContext.CLIENT);
        Connection connection = new Connection(ctx, "localhost", 5672, "guest", "guest");
        connection.setExceptionListener(new ExceptionListener() {

            @Override
            public void onException(Exception error) {
                System.out.println("Problem with AMQP connection: " + error.getMessage());
            }
        });

        connection.connect();

        // Parameters are maximum number of unsettled input and output messages
        Session session = connection.createSession(50, 50);

        Consumer consumer = session.createConsumer("jms.queue.TEST", 100, QoS.AT_LEAST_ONCE, false, null);

        Producer producer = session.createProducer("jms.queue.TEST", QoS.AT_LEAST_ONCE);
        AMQPMessage message = new AMQPMessage();
        message.setAmqpValue(new AmqpValue(new AMQPString("Test String")));

        producer.send(message);
        producer.close();

        System.out.println("Attempting to read a message.");
        message = consumer.receive(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(1));
        if (message != null) {
            AMQPType payload = message.getAmqpValue().getValue();
            System.out.println("Message payload = " + payload.toString());
        } else {
            System.out.println("Did not get a message in the time given.");
        }

        connection.close();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwitftMQTest testCase = new SwitftMQTest();

        try {
            testCase.run();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Problem with AMQP connection: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a prefix on artemis queues. Usually you have to specify the name as jms.queue.QueueName...

I added this answer originally as we were investigating what was your issue. (I work with Tim Bish, the guy who gave the other answer). it was not the case on the end, but I wanted to keep this answer here as that could be the case eventually for certain users googling.